# Determine whether column generation heuristic is optimal?

Tags: column-generation, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

I am currently working on a machine scheduling problem formulated as MILP and trying to solve it with Column Generation. Since I do not use Branch-n-Price, but only Column Generation as heuristic, it can happen that the heuristic solves the model globally optimal, but often not. How can I determine whether the model has been solved optimally without having to solve the entire model to optimality? And how do I then calculate the optimality gap?

Answer (score 1):

In any iteration of Column Generation, you can calculate the Lagrangian bound, provided that you solve the pricing problem to optimality (you can easily find on Internet how to calculate such bound). If the maximum value (for a minimization problem) of this Lagrangian bound (over all col.gen. iterations) coincides with the value of your heuristic solution, the latter is optimal. Optimality gap is the difference between the two.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can then calculate this Lagranigan bound for the final master problem with the columns and the restored integrality, right? Or for all Masterproblems for all iterations?

Comment: Usually, it suffices to calculate the Lagrangian bound for the last iteration of the column generation (again, provided that you solved the pricing to optimality in this iteration).

Comment: I see. Thank you. Yes I solve the SPs to optimality. However am I able to compute the Lagranigan Bound even though I don't use anything Lagranigan related in my CG algorithm? Or do you in how to compute it in Gurobi by any chance?

Comment: If the best reduced cost is zero then the Lagrangian bound is equal to the solution value of the restricted master LP.

Comment: Well I solve the SPs to optimality and the add columns as long as the RC are <-1-e6. Would that also work?

Comment: Yes, this would work too.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to add up the reduced costs over all SPs + the value of the relaxed RMP. And if this sum coincides with the final integer solution value, then it is optimal correct? However what I find odd, that using the approach I get the result that the solution I find is not optimal, but if I solve the same Modell instance using the compact model and the standard gurobi solver for instance, I get the same integer solution, which Gurobi declares as optimal. Why could that be the case?

Comment: This is completely normal. Your approach is heuristic, so it may terminate without optimality proof, even if the final solution is optimal.

Comment: Okay I see. And there is also no way to proof optimality for a column generation Heurisitc correct?

Comment: There is no way to prove optimality in every case, but in some cases (described above) you may accidentally do it.

Comment: To confirm this once again. If the Lagranigan Bound, i.e. LP bound + sum over all reduced costs) = IP solution, then the IP solution is provably optimal, otherwise the IP solution can also be optimal, but it cannot prove it

Comment: Yes__________________.